# google map - mark section after click pin

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I have page with 2 sides -

On one side I have sections. Each one is a day in a trip that contain texts and locations. On the other I have a Google map with pins that refer to sections.

I would like to allow user to click on the pin and the page will scroll to the relevant section and also to paint the section with background color.

Ans also the opposite - when user click on some section than the relevant pin will change his color.

I'm not sure how to do it with Google-Maps...

This is my script code:

```
<!-- Google map -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=fUA&callback=initMap" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     var markers = [

            {
                "title": "Praho",
                "lat": "50.075538",
                "lng": "14.437801",
                "description": "Day: 1"
            }           
         , 
            {
                "title": "Český ráj",
                "lat": "50.586675",
                "lng": "15.157302",
                "description": "Day: 2"
            }           
         , 
            {
                "title": "Bešeňová",
                "lat": "49.100211",
                "lng": "19.434720",
                "description": "Day: 3"
            }           
            ];
    var infoWindows = []; // for open/close button

    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
        zoom: 7,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP // HYBRID
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);   

    window.onload = function () {

        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var lat_lng = new Array();
        var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            lat_lng.push(myLatlng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                title: data.title
            });

            latlngbounds.extend(marker.position);

            // open popup by click
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
            //


            // Open all popups
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: '<div id="iw-container">' +'<div class="iw-title">' + data.description + '</div>' + '</div>',
                maxWidth: 350
            });

        /*  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function () {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        */  
            infowindow.open(map, marker);               
            //
            //Open/close infoWindow - Store all marker and infowindow in JSON array...
            var dict_map = {};
            dict_map['infoWinObj'] = infowindow;
            dict_map['markerObj'] = marker;

            //push JSON dict in array
            infoWindows.push(dict_map);               
            //  
        }
        map.setCenter(latlngbounds.getCenter());
    //  map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

        //***********ROUTING****************//

        //Initialize the Path Array
        var path = new google.maps.MVCArray();

        //Initialize the Direction Service
        var service = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

        //Set the Path Stroke Color
        var poly = new google.maps.Polyline({ map: map, strokeColor: '#4986E7' });

    }

    function closeAllInfoWindows()
    {
        for (var i=0;i<infoWindows.length;i++) {
           if (infoWindows[i]['infoWinObj'])
              infoWindows[i]['infoWinObj'].close();
        }
    } 

    function openAllInfoWindows()
    {
        for (var i=0;i<infoWindows.length;i++) {                   
              infoWindows[i]['infoWinObj'].open(map, infoWindows[i]['markerObj']);
        }
    }   

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a basic demo.

The main idea are `panTo()` marker and `scrollTop()` to the day block you clicked.

Edit: Include tiltes and content in the DayInfo array. Now you can build what your want in infowindow.

```js
var map;
var StartPoint = new google.maps.LatLng(50, 10);

var DayInfo = [{
    ID: "day1",
    Title: "Title1",
    Content: "Content1",
    Location: new google.maps.LatLng(51.72977747627091, 6.605224609375),
  },
  {
    ID: "day2",
    Title: "Title2",
    Content: "Content2",
    Location: new google.maps.LatLng(52.78551578550006, 13.460693359375),
  },
  {
    ID: "day3",
    Title: "Title3",
    Content: "Content3",
    Location: new google.maps.LatLng(50.292175137097736, 14.32861328125),
  },
  {
    ID: "day4",
    Title: "Title4",
    Content: "Content4",
    Location: StartPoint
  }
]

var DaysMarker = [];

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    center: StartPoint,
    zoom: 7,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

  DayInfo.forEach(function(dayInfo, index) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: dayInfo.Location,
      map: map,
      isOpended: false,

      Open: function() {
        if (!this.isOpended) {
          this.infowindow.open(map, marker)
          this.isOpended = true
        }
        map.panTo(this.position)
      }
    })

    marker.infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      content: '<div id="iw-container">' +
        '<h1>' + dayInfo.Title + '</h1>' +
        '<div class="iw-title">' +
        'Day' + (index + 1) + '<br>' +
        dayInfo.Content +
        '</div>' + '</div>',
      maxWidth: 350
    });

    marker.addListener('click', function() {
      if (this.isOpended) {
        this.infowindow.close()
        this.isOpended = false
      } else {
        this.Open()
        // var offsetTop = $('.day').get(index).offsetTop;
        $('html, body').animate({
          // scrollTop: offsetTop
          scrollTop: $('#' + dayInfo.ID).offset().top
        }, '500');
      }
    })

    DaysMarker.push(marker)
  })
}

$(function() {
  initialize()

  $('.day').on('click', function() {
    var index = $(this).index();
    DaysMarker[index].Open()
    // var offsetTop = $('.day').get(index).offsetTop;
    $('html, body').animate({
      // scrollTop: offsetTop
      scrollTop: $(this).offset().top
    }, '500');
  })
})
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body>div {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#map {
  width: 70%;
  position: fixed !important;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#days {
  margin-left: -4px;
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.day {
  height: 100vh;
  outline: 1px blue solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>


<div id="days">
  <div id="day1" class="day">Day1</div>
  <div id="day2" class="day">Day2</div>
  <div id="day3" class="day">Day3</div>
  <div id="day4" class="day">Day4</div>
</div>
<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, but what about the title/description for each pin?

Comment: Here's an example showing how to set the title and description. [Google Map API Doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/infowindow-simple?hl=EN)

Comment: But in my code I added title to array - ` var markers = [...]` . is it possible to add title to yours - `var Locations = [...]` ?

Comment: I just edited the post as per your comment's requirement.

Comment: Thank you very much! if i can than just one last thing - in your code, when i click on the pin the page scroll to the right div. you use "index" for that. that's greet, but in my code i give to each div/section unique ID. can i implement this ID in the `var DayInfo = [..]` array and use in to mark the scroller anchor ?

Comment: Yes, you just have to change the scroll method. I comment out the original one in case someone prefer using it.

Comment: Thank you! I'm truly appreciate your help...!